# Heroku App Going To Sleep Even Though Icon Shows It Won't

Tags: heroku, dyno

In the docs for Heroku- [App Sleeping on Heroku](https://blog.heroku.com/app_sleeping_on_heroku)- it says that apps with a **filled in hexagon icon** will never go to sleep.

Mine has that icon, but still goes to sleep:

[image]
-*from [App Sleeping on Heroku](https://blog.heroku.com/app_sleeping_on_heroku)*

Unlike the **outlined** hexagon with zzz's pictured above, when my app goes to sleep, the icon becomes a **filled in** hexagon icon with zzz's.

Why is my app going to sleep if the icon is indicating it won't? It this just old documentation on Heroku?

Comment: That's not documentation, it's a blog post from 2013. When I hover over that icon in the Heroku console, it just says it indicates "App is awake" - I presume its meaning has shifted somewhat since 2013, as they changed how free dynos worked since then. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours for how to prevent sleep.

Comment: Ahh yes, thanks for bringing that to my attention. Must just be a screenshot of old icons on an old out of date blog.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, that's an old Heroku *blog* post not a *doc*. Must be an out of date screenshot. The icons must have changed since then.